# PHP script for Wordpress for Comment Approval

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to write PHP script (standalone) for comment approval.

**Objective**:
I use Aksimet for comment filtering. After Akismet's filtering, few comments get passed and come to my email for approval. I will get comment ID from there and pass it to the script in get parameter (manually).

This way I do not need to login to WP every time. The script will just approve comment so there is not much risk or harm. If script works then It will take less time and I can approve comment any time even from office.

---

I tried setting the moderation bit in MySQL directly to see if it works or not! The answer is yes and no. It approves the comment but it does not refresh the post. So, my cache show post without new comment. I use Super cache plugin.

The challenge is to write script OUTSIDE of WP environment. So, that I can access the script without Admin login.

Please suggest trick for this and how to start for this.

Comment: Have you attempted working directly in MySQL (as you tried) with the Super cache plugin turned off? It sounds like that might be the root of the problem.

Comment: yes, but I cannot turn it off for this one. If I approve comment from Admin panel then cache automatically get cleared. So, thought if any expert in WP can give me tips on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a little time and got this working. The key is that you can use the WP API in your script by including wp-load.php.

I have tested this below and it works in my Wordpress. It uses GET parameters 'commentid' and 'status'. I leave it to you to extend, test for error conditions, provide appropriate security mechanisms, etc.

```
<?php
include('wp-load.php');

echo 'Running comment approval...<br>';
$wp_error = false;

if(isset($_GET['commentid']) && isset($_GET['status']) )
{   


        $comment_id = $_GET['commentid'];
        $comment_status_to_set = $_GET['status'];

        $current_status = wp_get_comment_status( $comment_id );

        echo 'Current comment status is ' . $current_status .'<br>';
        echo 'Setting status to ' . $comment_status_to_set . '<br>';

        $res = wp_set_comment_status($comment_id, $comment_status_to_set, $wp_error);        

        $new_current_status = wp_get_comment_status( $comment_id ); 
        echo 'Now status is ' . $new_current_status . '<br>';
}
else
{
    echo 'No comment parameters passed in url';
}

?>
```

And here is the usage for wp_set_comment_status, from the source code:

- @param int $comment_id Comment ID.
- @param string $comment_status New comment status, either 'hold', 'approve', 'spam', or 'delete'.
- @param bool $wp_error Whether to return a WP_Error object if there is a failure. Default is false.
- @return bool False on failure or deletion and true on success.

Also, so those who are curious know how I went about solving this... basically I checked the /wp-includes/ directory of WP to see if there were any comment related files. There is a file called comment.php in there, which has most, if not all, of the main comment manipulation functions that the wordpress API uses.

Comment: I will check and reply again here. Because you used WP API then   cache should not create problem. I will come back again. I will just up-vote it for now. Your solution that suggest I can use wp-load.php so easily will be very useful for hacks. :) thanks

Comment: Sorry! I could not check this. I assume this sample is working. The way code is written is correct and help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@param int $comment_id Comment ID.
@param string $comment_status New comment status, either 'hold', 'approve', 'spam', or 'delete'.
@param bool $wp_error Whether to return a WP_Error object if there is a failure. Default is false.
@return bool False on failure or deletion and true on success.